# Mongo DB - net.bindIp for local and network access

Tags: mongodb

I want the mongod instance to be accessible both from the localhost and other servers on the network.

If I set the `net.bindIp` value to `127.0.0.1` then mongod doesn't listen to external connections and `nmap -p 27017 <server>` reports that the port is `closed`. The same occurs if I comment out the `net.bindIp` line in `mongod.conf`.

If I set the `net.bindIp` value to the local IP address - `192.168.0.10` - then mongod listens for network connections on port 27017, but it doesn't allow me to connect to the mongod instance from the local host using the `mongo` command.

What value do I need to set `net.bindIp` to, to ensure I can connect both locally and over the network to the mongod instance.

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include both the localhost and network IP address as comma separated values.

```
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.10
```

and restart the service

```
sudo service mongod restart
```